# replace row value with the previous value if the difference between them is less than a fixed value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
Index  Value
0        5
1        Nan
2        6
3        16
4        23
5        32
6        33
7        34
```

if the difference with the previous row is less than 2, the current row value has to be equal to previous row only.

So I want it like

```
Index  Value
0        5
1        Nan
2        6
3        16
4        23
5        32
6        32
7        32
```

```
I have tried : 

test = np.where(df.Value.notnull() & df.Value.shift(-1).notnull() & ((df.Value - df.Value.shift(-1)) < 2),df.Value.shift(-1),df.Value)
```

its not giving the desired output, where am i going wrong?

Edit:

Hi, i have a small modifocation in my requiremement. If the previous value is null, i want it to be compared with the before non-null value and calculate the difference. So in this case i want it to be

```
Index  Value
0        5
1        Nan
2        5
4        23
5        32
6        32
7        32
```

Index-2 value should be 5 only not 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `diff` and `cumsum` create the groupkey , then we using `transform`

```
s=df.Value.diff()
df.groupby((s.isnull()|s.gt(2)).cumsum()).Value.transform('first')
0     5.0
1     NaN
2     6.0
3    16.0
4    23.0
5    32.0
6    32.0
7    32.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

Update hehe

```
s=df.Value.diff()
print(df.groupby((s.gt(2)).cumsum()).Value.transform('first').mask(df.Value.isnull()))
0     5.0
1     NaN
2     5.0
3    16.0
4    23.0
5    32.0
6    32.0
7    32.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Chinni see your last line , the value is for 2 row above only using shift will not get that value even the condition looks right

Comment: @Wen-Ben just curious if it can be done using `.rolling()` ??

Comment: @anky_91 I feel like rolling is hard to do with this , since the windows is hard to determined

Comment: Hi @Wen-Ben, thanks for the solution, i have a small modifocation in my requiremement. If the previous value is null, i want it to be compared with previous non-null value and calculate the difference.

Comment: @Chinni dropna then reindex back